# Unable to use the gatling conf using maven command

Tags: maven, gatling, scala-gatling

I have been using Gatling Config file in my Gatling Project

conf file name : gatling.conf
file is placed under src/test/resources

When I run the test using the engine class it automatically pick the conf file
Although when I tried to run the test using maven command it doesn't identify the Gatling conf file configurations

Sample command used to run the test is
mvn clean  gatling:test -Dgatling.simulationClass=PerformanceTest -Dgatling.conf.file=gatling.conf

Comment: Your setup is correct. Are you sure you have properly uncommented and removed the # on the lines you've changed?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to resolve this by doing below steps

Copied logback-test.xml into src/test/resources which was previously in the src/scala